# How to call an activity from a Dialogfragment in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nullpointerexception, android-dialogfragment

I want to call an activity from Dialogfragment, I have attached the code and logcat below for your reference on what I have tried.Kindly provide me your knowledge on it. Thank you.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LinkActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Logcat:

> 02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670):  at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:75)
>   02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670):  at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:3122)
>   02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670):  at com.firstadvantage.activities.LogDialog.LinkActivity(LogDialog.java:93)
>   02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670):  at com.firstadvantage.activities.LogDialog$3.onCommandFinished(LogDialog.java:75)
>   02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670):  at com.firstadvantage.buisnesslayer.commands.Command$3.run(Command.java:85)
>   02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   02-12 13:47:17.345: E/AndroidRuntime(670):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13338148/4385913)

Comment: In which line getting NPE?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K its in line 93..

Comment: can you guys paste a snippet or an example for it

Comment: Bad question, bad answers, SO would be better off if this was deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to call from Fragment to Activity that hosts the Fragment:

1. Simply casting to HostActivity

   ```
   ((HostActivity) getActivity()).methodInActivity();
   ```
2. Use interface in Fragment as listener, HostActivity implements the listener:

   ```
   private SuperListener hostActivity;

   //In Fragment, define interfce
   public interface SuperListener{
       //for example a confirm dialog
       void getDialogOk(View dialogView);
   }

   //in constructor, get listener instance from HostActivity
   public YourDialogFragment(SuperListener hostActivity)
   {
      this.hostActivity = hostActivity;
   }

   //when `Ok` clicked
   hostActivity.getDialogOk(dialogView);
   ```

Hope this is clear.

Comment: I want to call ActivityIntent how can I do that Xingchen

Comment: getActivity().getIntent();