# How to add an item to a listview via custom dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-dialog

I created a custom dialog box android activity in a separate class.
The dialog box has a button which adds an item to `listview` whenever it is clicked.
The list view is declared in the base activity.

Comment: You have to store that value locally and then use it in  that activity to set list.

Comment: Your question is badly formatted. Could you provide us with your existing code?

Comment: provide more information please! Which listview adapter are you using? how does the dialog add the item? how is the listview being decalred?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a combination of `DialogFragment and Callback` for this issue.

Implement like this answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338113/managing-activity-from-dialogfragment), and make some adjustments. in your button `onClick()`, call `YourInterface.method()`.

This will trigger the method you override on your `BaseActivity`, which you do add a item into your `ListView`.